How to get the number of background tasks currently running in a FastAPI application?
The below run_tasks FastAPI route handler spawns a background task on each HTTP call to the /run-tasks endpoint.
import asyncio
import time

from fastapi import APIRouter
from starlette.background import BackgroundTasks


router = APIRouter()


async def background_task(sleep_time: int, task_id: int):
    print(f"Task {task_id} started")
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)  # Simulate a long-running task
    print(f"Task {task_id} completed")


@router.post("/run-tasks")
async def run_tasks(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, sleep_time: int):
    background_tasks.add_task(background_task, sleep_time, int(time.time()))
    print(len(background_tasks.tasks))
    return {"message": "NEW SLEEP query arg background task started"}

When a SIGTERM signal is sent to the process running this FastAPI app, the following sequence is observed in the logs:

Waiting for background tasks to complete appears.
Afterward, messages like "Task {some_id} completed" are logged.
Finally, the log shows "Waiting for application shutdown", and the
application then shuts down.

Is there a way to get how many background tasks are currently running? I'd like to print the number of remaining tasks after each task completion (i.e., after print(f"Task {task_id} completed")).
My goal is to see '0' at the end, so that to be sure that all background tasks finished, before application shutdown.
I understand that a FastAPI app running in Python should wait for all background tasks to finish. However, I want to ensure this also happens when the app runs inside a container within a Kubernetes pod. This is crucial for correctly tuning the terminationGracePeriodSeconds parameter of the pod (see the relevant Termination of Pods documentation).

starlette BackgroundTasks is a fairly simple class, and it has  a .tasks attribute which is a plain list. - As your snippet shows, len(background_tasks.tasks) will yield the number of running tasks.
Once you are done with your view code, however, FastApi makes a different usage of the BackgroundTasks class - directly from fastapi docs: "FastAPI knows what to do in each case and how to reuse the same object, so that all the background tasks are merged together and are run in the background afterwards"  ( https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/es/tutorial/background-tasks/ )
So, even if you get hold of your instance in another long running code in order to monitor the BackgroundTasks object itself, the len approach would be unpredictable.
What you can do is wrap each item you add to background tasks in a asyncio.Task you produce yourself - it will be awaited as usual by the framework code, but you can then attach callbacks for when its done, and keep their count - even across several HTTP requests.
This requires however that you add these tasks to your own container, (or otherwise keep a global counter).
To avoid simply throwing these counters in your global namespace, please check the docs on liespam events here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/ -
in this simplified example I will skip that.
import asyncio
import time

from fastapi import APIRouter
from starlette.background import BackgroundTasks


router = APIRouter()

my_bg_tasks = set()

def task_adder(background_tasks, callable: "CoroutineFunction", *args, **kwargs):
     loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
     task = loop.create_task(callable(*args, **kwargs)
     my_bg_tasks.add(task)
     background_tasks.add_task(task)
     task.add_done_callback(task_counter)

def task_counter(task):
    my_bg_tasks.pop(task)
    print(f"Number of current running tasks: {len(my_bg_tasks)}"
    # optinionally do something with the task return value
    # (ordinarily not acessible):
    result = task.result()
    ...
    

async def background_task(sleep_time: int, task_id: int):
   ...


@router.post("/run-tasks")
async def run_tasks(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, sleep_time: int):
    task_adder(background_tasks, background_task, sleep_time, int(time.time()))
    print(len(background_tasks.tasks))
    return {"message": "NEW SLEEP query arg background task started"}




Unfortunately, Starlette does not, currently, provide any native way to get the state of background tasks that have been created in a FastAPI/Starlette application. You could, however, achieve that, using one of the solutions provided below.
Solution 1
Create your own background tasks, following the example given in Python's official  documentation page on Creating Tasks. To that end, you will need asyncio.create_task() (you may have a look at Option 3 of this answer for more details on that function). The asyncio.create_task() function takes a coroutine (i.e., an async def) function, and creates a Task that is executed inside the event loop of the current thread. As described in the linked answer earlier, one could, alternatively, call asyncio.get_running_loop() to get the current event loop, and then call loop.create_task() (or, if it was meant to run on a different thread from the main one, you could get/create the event loop of that thread).
If the background task function, however, was not a coroutine one, but a synchronous blocking function that would block the event loop—and hence, the entire server—when called, until is completed (take a look at this answer for more details on async def vs def functions in FastAPI, and Python, in general), then that function should be run in a separate thread and then awaited, using either Starlette's run_in_threadpool() (which is used by Starlette on such occasions, behind the scenes, when using FastAPI/Starlette's BackgroundTasks—see relevant implementation) or Python's loop.run_in_executor() (see this answer for more details and performance tests between the two).
At application startup, you should initialize a Python set to be used for your background_tasks and add that object to request.state, using a lifespan handler, as explained here. Inside the endpoints, you could access that object, using, for instance, request.state.background_tasks, which would be used to add the newly created tasks. For each Task that is created, you would add a callback function to be run when the Task is done. This could be achieved using the add_done_callback() method, which would be used to remove a task's reference from the set after completion.
Optionally, you could have check_pending_tasks() function running, as shown below, to periodically check for the remaining background tasks to be completed. Again, optionally (and certainly, not necessarily), you could have create_background_task() run in a Starlette BackgroundTask and attach it to the response, as in the way is currently implemented, the background task will actualy be executed just before returning the response. This, however, should not be an issue, as asyncio.create_task() actually executes the task in the "background" (without waiting for its completion), i.e., concurrently with all other tasks in the event loop, switching between them at await points.
Working Example
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi.concurrency import run_in_threadpool
import asyncio
import time
import inspect
import uuid


async def check_pending_tasks(background_tasks: set):
    while True:
        for task in background_tasks:
            #print(task)
            print(task.get_coro())
        
        print(f"{len(background_tasks)} Background Tasks Pending...\n")        
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        
        
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    background_tasks = set()
    asyncio.create_task(check_pending_tasks(background_tasks))
    yield {'background_tasks': background_tasks}


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


def create_background_task(background_tasks, func, *args, **kwargs):
    if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(func):
        task = asyncio.create_task(func(*args, **kwargs))
    else:
        task = asyncio.create_task(run_in_threadpool(func, *args, **kwargs))
        
    background_tasks.add(task)
    task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard)
    
    
async def background_task(sleep_time: int, task_id: int):
    print(f"Task {task_id} started")
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(f"Task {task_id} completed")


def sync_background_task(sleep_time: int, task_id: str):
    print(f"Task {task_id} started")
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(f"Task {task_id} completed")


@app.post("/create/{sleep_time}")
async def create_task(request: Request, sleep_time: int):
    background_tasks = request.state.background_tasks
    
    # create background task using a coroutine function
    create_background_task(background_tasks, background_task, sleep_time, str(uuid.uuid4()))
    
    # create background task using a non-coroutine function
    #create_background_task(background_tasks, sync_background_task, sleep_time, int(time.time()))
    
    return {"message": "New background task has been created"}

Solution 2
The second solution is based on this answer, which explains how to get all pedning tasks of an event loop. This solution allows you to keep using FastAPI/Starlette's BackgroundTasks, but may be less recommended due to the fact that it might be hard to differentiate BackgroundTasks from other coroutines that run in the event loop. It has been noted that a BackgroundTask appears as a RequestResponseCycle.run_asgi coroutine object (given that you are using Uvicorn as your ASGI server) in the list of pending tasks (using asyncio.all_tasks()—see linked answer above for more details), but the same object appears for incoming requests, for instance (you could check that if you used, for example, await asyncio.sleep(10) in another endpoint, without creating any background tasks inside, and create a call to it). That means, that, at least, both BackgroundTasks and other uncompleted requests may appear in the same list of Tasks with the same coroutine object (but, of course, different memory address), which may or may not make things harder for you to tell whether or not this is a background task pending completion (always depending on your needs).
In the following example, for instance, you can tell that a RequestResponseCycle.run_asgi coroutine object in the pending tasks list is a Starlette BackgroundTask, as there is no other endpoint that may take that long enough to finish, in order to end up appearing in the pending tasks list. On the other hand, using this solution, you may be able to see every other pending task that is preventing your application from shutting down, until is completed.
Again, depending on one's needs, they may choose either solution.
Working Example
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import asyncio
import uuid


async def check_pending_tasks():
    while True:
        counter = 0
        for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
            #print(task.get_coro())
            coro = str(task.get_coro())
            if "RequestResponseCycle.run_asgi" in coro:
                counter += 1
        
        print(f"{counter} Background Tasks Pending...\n")        
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        
        
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    asyncio.create_task(check_pending_tasks())
    yield


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


async def background_task(sleep_time: int, task_id: str):
    print(f"Task {task_id} started")
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(f"Task {task_id} completed")


@app.post("/create/{sleep_time}")
async def create_task(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, sleep_time: int):
    background_tasks.add_task(background_task, sleep_time, str(uuid.uuid4()))
    return {"message": "New background task has been created"}

Solution 3
A third, and likely more simple solution for your case (since you only need to keep track of the amount of tasks remaining to be completed) is to have a set of unique task ids, which would be generated and added to the set once a background task is created and, finally, be discarded as soon as the task is completed—just like in Solution 1 above, but with using FastAPI/Starlette's BackgroundTasks instead. You can create that set at the application startup and share it among the various endpoints using request.state, as demonstrated earlier in Solution 1.
Working Example
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, BackgroundTasks
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import asyncio
import uuid


async def check_pending_tasks(background_tasks: set):
    while True:
        for task in background_tasks:
            print(task)
        
        print(f"{len(background_tasks)} Background Tasks Pending...\n")        
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        
        
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    background_tasks = set()
    asyncio.create_task(check_pending_tasks(background_tasks))
    yield {'background_tasks': background_tasks}


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


async def background_task(background_tasks: set, sleep_time: int, task_id: str):
    print(f"Task {task_id} started")
    background_tasks.add(task_id)
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(f"Task {task_id} completed")
    background_tasks.discard(task_id)


@app.post("/create/{sleep_time}")
async def create_task(request: Request, tasks: BackgroundTasks, sleep_time: int):
    background_tasks = request.state.background_tasks
    tasks.add_task(background_task, background_tasks, sleep_time, str(uuid.uuid4()))
    return {"message": "New background task has been created"}

